# Wagtail Elasticsearch failed on tags

Tags: elasticsearch, tags, customization, wagtail

I created a customised Document model in wagtail admin by

```
class CustomizedDocument(Document):
    ...
```

And i have updated settings.WAGTAILDOCS_DOCUMENT_MODEL.

However, i realised my search on tags fails. I suspect there is something to do with elasticsearch. But i m really new to that.

Here is the tracestack message from elasticsearch

```
[INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [oceLPbj] starting ...
[INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [oceLPbj] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9300}, {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [oceLPbj] new_master {oceLPbj}{oceLPbjSQ7ib2pTjx9gpPg}{WDDcwdlISnu-EW8mjQcOxQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [oceLPbj] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9200}, {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [oceLPbj] started
[INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [oceLPbj] recovered [4] indices into cluster_state
[INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [oceLPbj] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[wagtail__wagtaildocs_document][1], [wagtail__wagtaildocs_document][3]] ...]).
[INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [oceLPbj] [wagtail__wagtaildocs_document_awv9f81] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [oceLPbj] [wagtail__wagtaildocs_document_awv9f81/CzKReMnsQ9qziLnOQQ5K3g] create_mapping [wagtaildocs_abstractdocument_wagtaildocs_document_distributor_portal_customizeddocument]
[INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [oceLPbj] [wagtail__wagtaildocs_document_awv9f81/CzKReMnsQ9qziLnOQQ5K3g] create_mapping [wagtaildocs_abstractdocument_wagtaildocs_document]
```

Could anyone help me find out what's going on here? Any help is appreciated. Let me know what else information i should provide.

Comment: Firstly, your model should be inheriting from `AbstractDocument` rather than `Document`. Secondly, the output from elasticsearch doesn't seem to indicate any error (all lines are prefixed with `INFO`, rather than warning or error) - please can you describe what exactly is failing? (Are you performing the search from code, within the admin, or on your site front-end? Is there an error message, or does it just not return the expected results?)

Comment: @gasman, Thanks for your comment. i am searching within the admin. And there is no error message. It just not return the expected results. I will try inherit from `AbstractDocument` instead of `Document`. If that solves the problem, it means elasticsearch backend is not supporting inherited class.

Comment: @gasman, changing to AbstractDocument still does not work.